# Is it possible to sort related_entries?

Tags: related-entries

When I'm pulling related_entries into a channel:entries tag, I want to be able to sort those related entries (for example by date).

Example:

```
{related_entries id="related_field" orderby="entry_date"}
```

I know that the above orderby parameter is not accepted by the related_entries tag, but is there any other clever way to get those entries sorted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [P&T's Playa](http://pixelandtonic.com/playa/docs/templates) a lot these days for relationships but, if you don't need all that raw power, my advise would be to flip your logic a bit and use [reverse_related_entries](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html#reverse-related-entries-tag-pair) which support orderby and sort parameters.

Comment: Thanks, using reverse_related_entries in this case would become very unlogical, so I'm going to use Playa. I've implemented it before, so should be a quick fix.